# Changing a file's URL without physically moving it

Tags: apache, url

I have a site, running Linux + Apache.

I have a file in my root directory, let's say file.php.
I want the URL to the file to be "domain.com/newdir/file.php", but I don't want to actually create the newdir and move the file there because it would be a huge hassle to update many many links all over my site.
Is there a way to accomplish this, meaning making the file accessible by the new URL without moving it?

Thank you.

Comment: [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)?

Answer (score 0):

On this site: [workwith.me](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite), you can find information about .htaccess and mod_rewrite. For your example you have to make a file called **.htaccess** and put it in the root directory. The file should contain these directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^newdir/file.php$ /file.php [L]
```

You can do this for every file you want to *rename*.

Answer (score 0):

Four possible solutions I can think of:

1. If your OS supports it, create a symlink:

   ```
   mkdir /home/foo/htdocs/newdir
   ln -s /home/foo/htdocs/file.php home/foo/htdocs/newdir/file.php
   ```

   ... and make sure Apache is [configured to follow them](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#Options):

   ```
   Options FollowSymLinks
   ```
2. Create an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) or [AliasMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#AliasMatch) (probably overkill)
3. Good old [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

   ```
   RewriteEngine One
   RewriteRule ^newdir/file\.php$ file.php [L]
   ```
4. Ugly: use a [custom 404 error page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#errordocument) with a PHP script that checks `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

I guess the standard solutions are #1 and #3.